# Nodejs: sending json object

Tags: json, node.js, express

Setting up a simple server,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var rooms = {};
....
app.listen(port, function(){console.log('Server Starts...\n');});
```

In a generic handler code I can send a json file like this:

```
app.post('/test',function(req,res){
    .....
    json = { 'status' = true, 'id' = new_id };
    res.end(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

Or just like this:

```
app.post('/test',function(req,res){
    .....
    json = { 'status' = true, 'id' = new_id };
    res.json(json);
});
```

stringify is converting it in string (this is clear) but when it is bettere to use this or that?
Are there any better methods for sending json object with express?

In both case, how can I handle the reception of the object?

I tried the following code:

```
newid: function(){
        var new_id;
        $.post('/test',new_id);
        return new_id;
    }
```

But the javascript in my html file is not able to see it (undefined):

```
<script>            
            var test = function() {
                json = newid();
                alert(json);
            }
....
<button onclick="test()">NewId</button><br>
....
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). `{ 'status' = true, 'id' = new_id }` is also not a "JSON file", nor is it a file, nor is it JSON (it's not even JavaScript, it's a syntax error). You must get your terminology right because if you confuse it all into one big mess it will be very difficult for you to reason about your tasks.

Comment: Use http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for making it working with the second option described from the server-side:

```
...
json = { 'status' = true, 'id' = new_id };
res.json(json);
```

ofcourse, new_id is a variable in my code.
The changes was done on the client-side, I send a function instad of returning a value:

```
newid: function(){
        $.post('/test', function(data){
            if( data.status ) console.log(data.new_id)
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

As with the comments left on your original question what you are passing to the express .json function is an object, so your code should be more like:

```
app.post('/test',function(req,res){
    .....
    let responseObject = { 'status' = true, 'id' = new_id };
    res.json(responseObject);
});
```

This will return JSON the same as if you stringified it, but using .json also sets all the correct headers.

The reason why you can't see anything back from the server side code is that client side you are trying to use $.post synchronously where you should be sending a callback.   You also need to change the code as the $.post function expects you to send a callback as the second argument.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
newid: function(callback){
        $.post('/test', callback, 'json');
    }
```

Then you need to pass the callback function through

```
<script>            
            var test = function() {
                json = newid(function(object) {
                  alert(object);
                }
            }
....
<button onclick="test()">NewId</button><br>
....
```

Hope this helps.